# Why isn't autocomplete working for npm linked module?

Tags: typescript

I am working on a typescript module that I have linked using `npm link moduleA`.
I link it using `npm link` in example project. When I type the path fx `import {DbServiceProvider} from "moduleA"`, no problems, it loads correctly. But I want to be able to get autoimport and autocompletion for exported stuff. I'm using WebStorm.